# Using self-leveling cement as a wood stove's stove board?

Tags: woodstove

I am looking to create a stove board / hearth pad similar to what is shown in this image:

[image]

Except that mine will be in a corner. I have been unable to find this type of stove board, or even the name of it to search for it.

So, I thought I'd make my own.

I currently have ⅝" OSB as the subfloor, it's all completely exposed at this point.

For the stove board, I was thinking of doing 2x3 forms, much like one might do for creating forms for a foundation footing, and then pouring self-leveling cement inside of those forms, letting it dry and then removing the forms. The back of the forms (ie, the walls behind the stove) would be created by the existing 2x6 wall plates on the floor. This would give me a 1" stove board after the ½" in floor heating and ½" solid wood flooring is placed around it for the rest of the room.

Any thoughts on whether this is valid, stupid, terrible, etc.?

Comment: I take it the woodstove you're using calls for cementboard or another noncombustible substrate for the stoveboard?

Comment: Installation manual says: "If the floor is made of combustible material, then a
non-combustible floor protector is required between the floor and the stove. An example of a noncombustible floor protector is a hearth constructed with a continuous layer of tile, brick, slate, glass or another non-combustible facing. There is no R-value requirement." and "the stove does not require an insulated hearth pad."